# What does "Serial Voting Was Reversed" mean?

Tags: discussion

I see the message "Serial voting was reversed" in the Recent achievements list.

What does that mean?

Edit:
Again, serial voting was reversed last night. I wonder if this is happening more often?

Edit:
And yet again last night serial voting was reversed, then today a series of downvotes of very old posts. Oh well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically, the system detected that someone has consistently downvoted your content, this looks more like a personal action rather than your answers being "bad", so the serial voting has been reversed.

See the help page: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

And Meta explanation [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

> Voting fraud is the systematic voting against correct voting rationales. Fraud most often happens with a single user continually voting (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time. This is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

Comment: Thanks! Very odd...

Comment: This generally happens when you get someone wound up on a single answer, so they decide to retaliate by downvoting everything in sight just out of spite.

Comment: I see. I can't remember that happening before. Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, this has happened to me at least once.....the system will catch serial UP and DOWN voting.

Comment: If I recall, I believe it can occur with serial *up*-votes as well.

Comment: Very strange. A new blast of about 15 downvotes in the span of a few minutes today, including some very old answers. Someone is unhappy I guess.

Comment: Certainly looks that way.  We'll keep an eye on things and issue some education if required.  You should get those votes back tomorrow.

Comment: I just got +30 with the phrase "User was removed". Perhaps that's it. If so, I'm pretty sure I know who it was.

Comment: I've had it both ways on SO. I think I know who it was in both cases (one user was very unhappy with a comment I left on their answer, and another was so happy with my answer he went on an upvote spree.)

Comment: To be fair, voting sprees can also be valid. If I think your answer was interesting, I might check out your other top answers and upvote the good ones

Comment: @lucidbrot You'd think that, but that's not the case: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5775/92050

Comment: @Cyonis I would argue that if I think your answer was interesting and check out your other top answers, I would also check out the other answers in the thread - at least the ones voted higher than yours. I assume, then it should be a light-grey area(?)

Comment: @MisterPositive Interesting, because I've done serial upvoting in the past before when discovering a new user on the site and going through their past answers. I'd only upvote maybe half of their posts though not all so I hope that would still have gone through as valid votes. :)

Comment: @lucidbrot A difference between a valid voting spree and most invalid voting sprees is that any valid voting spree requires the voter to _read_ at least the answers voted on and probably also the questions. This takes time, so casting e.g. 8 votes in a minute is very unlikely to be from someone who has carefully read what they've been voting on. I think the system makes an attempt to not automatically mark 'sprees' spread out over normal time periods as fraud. (but it may keep a record anyway, to e.g. _do_ mark it as fraud if it forms a suspicious pattern)

Comment: Ah, man.  I was wondering where my stalkers went.  I actually kind of miss them ...

Comment: @WesleyLong - maybe your stalkers got bored and latched on to me. More serial voting reversed last night.

Comment: @MisterPositive - if it keeps happening every few nights, does that mean it's a single user repeatedly doing the serial voting, or is someone churning out new muppets to do the work for them?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Not 100% sure, but it could be.  There are a few very bored souls in the world.

Comment: Does the serial (down)voter suffer any penalty?